# Can PL variables change during SQL queries (why doesn't Oracle optimize my simple query)?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Today I stumbled upon a case where I would readily assume a simple optimization
as a no-brainer.

Suppose you have a table called `my_table` with a column named `my_column` and
you write a stored procedure like this:

```
procedure my_proc(a_value my_table.my_column%type := null) is
begin
    for i in (
        select another_column from my_table
        where  a_value is null or my_column = a_value)
    loop
      -- do something
    end loop;
end;
```

I've always assumed that the expression `a_value is null` is constant for the
sake of the select statement, or any expression consisting purely of PL variables and other constants for that
matter. In other words, it could safely be evaluated prior to the execution of
the query and substituted for a constant. In this code, for example, when
`a_value` is not passed, the query would be equivalent to

```
select another_column from my_table
```

Conversely, when the value is passed, the query would be equivalent to

```
select another_column from my_table
where my_column = a_value
```

For my surprise, this simple optimization is not made. The `a_value is null`
expression seems to get executed for every record on the table and, with a
sufficiently large table, the difference is noticeable even without any special
tools. I am using version 10 and would regard this optimization as a 2.0 or 3.0
feature that would have been done a long time ago.

There must be some reason for this, obviously. Maybe my assumption that PL
variables are constants to the eyes of the SQL query is not true. Maybe PL
variables *can* change during the execution of SQL queries. Do you know of any
such case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When Oracle needs to compile and optimize the SQL query it must create a query plan that will work no matter what the values of the bind variables will be, because that plan can be reused with the same query but different values later.

In the query, `select another_column from my_table where a_value is null or my_column = a_value` a_value is the bind variable. The query will only hard parsed into a query plan  once. It can not collapse to `select another_column from my_table` since the next call to the stored procedure may pass in a non-null a_value.

**EDIT** Adding an example.

Ask Tom has a [posting](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1669972300346534908) that deals with a more complicated version of this issue. Based on his answer.

Sample data:

```
create table my_table(my_column varchar2(10) null
    , another_column varchar2(10) null)
/
insert into my_table values('1', 'a');
insert into my_table values('2', 'b');
insert into my_table values('3', 'c');
insert into my_table values('4', 'd');
insert into my_table values('5', 'e');
insert into my_table values('6', 'f');
insert into my_table values('7', 'g');
insert into my_table values('8', 'h');
insert into my_table values('9', 'i');
insert into my_table values('10', 'j');
commit;
```

The procedure:

```
create or replace procedure my_proc(p_value in my_table.my_column%TYPE default null) is
    type l_rec_type is record(another_column my_table.another_column%TYPE);
    l_sql varchar2(32767) := 'select another_column from my_table where ';
    l_cursor sys_refcursor;
    l_record l_rec_type;
begin
    if p_value is null then 
        l_sql := l_sql || '(1=1 or :my_column is null)';
    else 
        l_sql := l_sql || '(my_column = :my_column)';
    end if;
    open l_cursor for l_sql using p_value;
    loop
        fetch l_cursor into l_record;
        exit when l_cursor%NOTFOUND;
        -- do something
        dbms_output.put_line(l_record.another_column);
    end loop;
    close l_cursor;
end my_proc;
/
```

Watch it run:

```
SQL> exec my_proc()
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec my_proc('2')
b

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Hmmm. Right. That's the problem: I assume the queries are dynamic and evaluated at runtime, but the PL program is parsed once and only the query plan is stored for later execution. Follow up question: would interpreting the queries dynamically as I suggest in the question make everything a lot more slower? I guess the answer is, as always, 'it depends' (on the program).

Comment: Yes it does depend. If you use dynamic SQL without bind variables, you'll probably be doing too much parsing. But the number of bind variables is different depending on whether you want to pass in a_value or not making it hard to use them. Ask Tom has a solution, see edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, Shannon. I get it now, but in your example I still don't understand why do we need to validate the parameter with this if statement. The query plan seems to be cached for the input string and reused with different bind variable values. I guess it is the same kind of trade off to make the query plan *after* substituting the bind variables.

Comment: The if statement is used to build two different queries, based on whether a_value is null or not. Each of those two queries will get a separate query plan that is cached. (Until the plan is aged out of the cache that is.)

Comment: Sure. I had just misunderstood it. I thought that since the query is dynamic anyway, the query plan would get built after binding the variables. I now understand that the query plan is built once and cached before binding the variables (and cannot be optimized).